# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Having issue and recieving this error when trying to get my test class to work.

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 7010J000001RUj5: []
>
> Class.EmailToLeadWilmslow.handleInboundEmail: line 30, column 1
> Class.EmailToLeadTest.it_should_execute_assignment_rules: line 48, column 1

***EmailToLeadWilmslow***

```
global class EmailToLeadWilmslow implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

 /**
 * Handling Inbound Email
 * @param Messaging.InboundEmail Email object
 * @param Messaging.InboundEnvelope Email enveloppe
 * @return Messaging.InboundEmailResult
 * @access global
 */
 global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

 Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

 Lead lead = new Lead();
 lead.FirstName = email.fromname.substring(0, email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
 lead.LastName = email.fromname.substring(email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
 lead.Description = email.plainTextBody;
 String textBody = email.plainTextBody;
 String companyName;
 Integer startPos = textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:');
 if (textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:') > -1) {
 Integer endPos = textBody.indexOf('.', textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:'));
 companyName = textBody.substring(startPos + 'CompanyName:'.length(), endPos);
 }
 lead.Company = companyName != NULL ? companyName : '(not provided)';
 lead.LeadSource = 'Rightmove - Canford';
 lead.Status = 'New';
 upsert lead;
 CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(campaignId='7010J000001RUj5', LeadId=lead.Id);
 upsert cm;

 
 
 LeadService.executeAssignmentAsync(new Set<Id>{lead.Id});
 
 return result;

 }

}
```

***EmailToLeadTest***

```
@isTest
private class EmailToLeadTest {

  @isTest
  static private void it_should_execute_assignment_rules()
  {

      Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
      Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope = new  Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
      
      //Create the email body
      email.plainTextBody = 'This should become a note';
      email.fromAddress = 'test@test.com';
      email.fromName = 'John Doe';
      String contactEmail = 'jsmith@salesforce.com';
      email.subject = 'Dummy Account Name 123';
      
      //create instance of class
      EmailToLead e = new EmailToLead();
      EmailToLeadCanford eCa = new EmailToLeadCanford();
      EmailToLeadWilmslow eW = new EmailToLeadWilmslow();
      
    Lead l = new Lead(
      FirstName = 'John',
      LastName = 'Doe',
      Description = 'Test Description',
      LeadSource = 'Rightmove',
      Status = 'New'
    );
    upsert l;

    Test.startTest();
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult resultE = e.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult resultEw = eW.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult resultEca = eCa.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    LeadService.executeAssignmentAsync(new Set<Id>{l.Id});
    Test.stopTest();
    
    System.assert (resultE.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');
    System.assert (resultEw.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');
    System.assert (resultEca.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');
    
    // Since allTest is disabled, it is impossible to execute Assignment Rules.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hard code your Campaign Id in your InboundEmail class. This following line is a big problem:

```
 CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(campaignId='7010J000001RUj5', LeadId=lead.Id);
```

1. It's not best practice to hard code record ID in code. You would better create a custom setting/metadata type to store this information.
2. By default a test class run independently from your organisation data. That means, 7010J000001RUj5 doesn't exist as a campaign when you test class run. That's why you have a `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` error. You will need to create your campaign in your test class and populate that line dynamically.
3. You can use real data in test class if really necessary by using `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`

Comment: point 3 - `if really really really really` necessary - No reason to use seeAllData in this use case. I saw an earlier version of this OP and surmised there is a specific Campaign the app is trying to exploit - in which case the campaign name should be in a custom setting or custom metadata type - and the apex should query for that

Comment: @cropredy I probably didn't insist enough on the "if necessary". ;-)